# Identify RF 433 MHz chip in remote to reproduce it

Tags: rf, 433mhz, remote

I've recently bought a ceiling fan (Suilon Cambil) and I wanted to automate it substituting the remote it comes with, with a DIY one connected to Alexa.

Main problem is that I haven't been able to identify the chip (image attached) and Suilon's support only told me that it uses 433 MHz signal.

I've tried researching it and using an Arduino with a MX-RM-5 V receiver, but it doesn't receive any signal.

Any help is welcomed.

[image: chip view]

I've finally acquired the rtl-usb Nooelec NESDR Mini2+.

I've tested rtl_433 without any luck (I receive weather stations data from my neighbours but nothing that could be from the remote).

I've also tried using Gqrx to try and see if I could locate the signal around the 433MHz, without any luck eother (although it's the first time I've used it and might be missing something).

Going back to the remote, I saw that the crystal in the PCB is marked as 24.000MHz, so I started wondering, do you know if it means 24MHz or 24000MHz? Assuming it means 24Mhz, is it really possible to send a 433Mhz signal with this crystal? Could be that the support gave me wrong information?

Ok then! Assuming that the transmission is a 433MHz.
Is there a way to estimate the exact frequency measuring the antenna?
Additionally, would it be crazy to bypass the antenna in the rtl-sdr by connecting a cable between the remote's antenna directly to the sdr-rtl?

Comment: research the patent for the device ... it may contain useful info

Comment: `it doesn't receive any signal` .... how did you connect it? ... what code did you use?

Comment: There's a very good chance it's a proprietary chip, or is only sold to companies with huge volumes.  As a backup, consider buying an extra remote and using analog switches to mimic button presses.

Comment: That crystal is 24MHz and, yes, it's possible to create a 433MHz signal with it.

Comment: Search the product information for an FCC ID - fcc filings have lots of information you may find useful for reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Well worth trying an SDR with analyser to see if you can just decode the signal. Rtl-sdr and rtl_433 are a good combo in my experience.

I've used this in the past to decode a couple of remotes, and oil meter, and the control for a cooker hood.  Once decoded it is then fairly simple to control from a microcontroller.